# Getting Error Msg - Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'

Tags: c#, asp.net-3.5

I am checking for values in a textbox to trigger a conditional statement, but am getting error messages.

```
if (txtAge.Text = "49") || (txtAge.Text = "59")
{
    txtNote.Text = "A valid picture ID must be submitted";
}
```

The error message I am getting is *Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'*

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you type this:

```
if (txtAge.Text = "49")
```

This basically is assigning "49" to `txtAge.Text`, and then returning that value as a **string** (equal to "49").

This is the same, essentially, as doing:

```
string tmp = txtAge.Text = "49";
if (tmp) { //...
```

However, you cannot do "if (stringExpression)", since an if statement only works on a boolean.  You most likely wanted to type:

```
if (txtAge.Text == "49" || txtAge.Text == "59")
{
```

Comment: Why is this failing than: `(c == "All" || c == "") ? "[ClientText] LIKE '%'" : "[ClientText] = '" + c + "'"`. `c` is a string variable.

Answer (score 7):

In the if statement replace `=` by `==`.

You're using the assignment operator instead of the equals comparison.

The syntax for the if statement is also not correct. Check [if-else (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5011f09h%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Remove the closing ) after "49" and the opening ( after ||

Comment: @lance: "59".Equals(txtAge.Text) also nicely solves that pesky "easy to visually parse code" problem too. If it's hard to write it should be hard to understand! ROCK ON! :)

Answer (score 1):

you cannot use "=" to compare strings. in this case you could use txtAge.Text.comparedTo("49") == 0 and so on

Answer (score 1):

Need to use `==` instead of `=`. Former is used for `comparison` while the later is for `assignment`.

A better way is to use `Equals` method

```
if (txtAge.Text.Equals("49") || txtAge.Text.Equals("59"))
{ 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing ='s.  Also, you may need another set of Brackets around the whole if statement.