# Cannot Implicitly Convert type 'string' to 'bool' textbox1

Tags: c#

I am Needing Help in my C# Code. I'm trying to make it to where the button Calls for `Textbox1`. If `textBox1` is equal to "Password", then go to next Form: `Admin...`

If, `textBox1` is not equal to "Password", Show message and Close Program...

Here is a snippet of my Code:

```
private void xButton6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text = "Password")
        {
            Helpers.ShowAdmin(this);

        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Access Denied" , "Alert");
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
```

What Am I Doing Wrong?

Comment: Equals in C# is 2 equal signs not 1. Use == like `textBox1.Text == "Password"`

Comment: To explain the error message itself: `var a = textBox1.Text = "Password"` will set `a` to "Password", whereas `var a = textBox1.Text == "Password"` will set `a` to true/false. `if` expects a boolean (true/false) value, but at the moment it's getting a string ("Password").

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting Error Msg - Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2357354/getting-error-msg-cannot-implicitly-convert-type-string-to-bool)

Answer (score 5):

You need to use double equals

```
if (textBox1.Text == "Password")
```

[== Operator (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/equality-comparison-operator)

> For predefined value types, the equality operator (==) returns true if
>   the values of its operands are equal, false otherwise. For reference
>   types other than string, == returns true if its two operands refer to
>   the same object. For the string type, == compares the values of the
>   strings.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the problem was that you needed double equal signs `==` for equality; however, just wanted to add that you can also use `textBox1.Text.Equals("Password")` which yields the same result.

Answer (score 0):

use == in Line if (textBox1.Text = "Password") instead of =

**it should be like**

```
if (textBox1.Text == "Password")
```

> '=' is used to assign value to variable while '==' is used to
>   comparision